# How to handle double-high status bar that appears when a phone call/skype call etc is in progress?

Tags: iphone, ios7, uiview, ios7-statusbar

How can I fix the layout issue when I am on a Phone call and open my iOS app? The app's view is being pushed down by 20px or so when the phone bar appears on top of the screen. In my storyboard, the UIView is marked Fixed (not freeform). Blue color is the top part of my app's View (hid the rest of the view for confidentiality)[image]

Comment: Which layout issue, what isn't being layed out properly? Show us the rest of the screen if it's something below the bar.

Comment: @Leena Nope, not yet.

Comment: Have you done any changes in deltas of view?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21817677/1790571 check this