# Wrong screen size after dismissing UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I have an iOS app like whatsapp & ...
when I present `UIImagePickerController` with `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera`  source type.

```
imagePicker = [UIImagePickerController new];
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
imagePicker.delegate = self;
imagePicker.mediaTypes =[NSArray arrayWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie,(NSString *)kUTTypeImage,nil];
[self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

**Problem**

Some times after cancel or finish capturing  `UIImagePickerController` in `Video` mode , when I back to my viewController (dismiss camera ) my input View (my Windows) going to bottom with 20 pixel ( status bar height ), I think my problem relate to this link [How to position view below green bar during phone call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947226/iphone-how-to-resize-view-when-call-status-bar-is-toggled) , because in video segment a recording status bar show for a few moment.
In some condition  my Windows (UITabbar in previous  controller going to bottom as same ) !!!

[image]

**Edit**

the solution works only in current View  but another View controller corrupt ( going to bottom )

Comment: It is always better to post your code, what you tried so far so that one can help you.

Comment: @Bharat please check again , ( i think it's very regular ) i'm not n00b :-/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Finally it's Fiexed**

special thanks to danialzahid94.

for Fix this issue , you should call

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        self.view.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds];
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
        self.tabBarController.view.frame  = [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds];
        [self.tabBarController.view layoutIfNeeded]; // for fixing  tabbar Controller 

    }];
```

in 2 Delegate :

> -(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
>   - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info

Comment: Oh right. I didn't know the whole viewController hierarchy gets disturbed. I'll keep this in mind next time.

Comment: I first see the bug like this in iOS 13. This solution fixes it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using auto layout, you could try `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` when the `UIImagePickerController` dismisses. If that doesn't work, you can get the screen size and assign it to your `self.view.frame` like this:

```
self.view.frame = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
```

This usually works for me.

Comment: my project is Auto Layout . i will try it at this time . let me to notify about this. i want to say a little note: after dismiss camera ( a little status bar recording with Red color appear for a second ( like call status bar ) , i think it cause this problem.

Comment: should i call self.view.layoutIfNeeded()  -(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
    
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
      [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];  OR out of this block ?

Comment: Yes, you will call it in that block. Do add the `self.view.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]` before calling `layoutIfNeeded`

Comment: i think only self.view.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds enough , let me to notify about final result :)

Comment: Also add those two lines in `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` delegate method if you have implemented it. The same way as you have added in `didCancel:`

Comment: yes ,  sure bro , i add these 2 lines in imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: as the same

Comment: i added  only self.view.frame = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds in compleation of block . should i call LayoutIfNeeded ? in some condition , our current viewController is ok as well but the parent of my ViewController ( in UINavigationController ) corrupt :(

Comment: You should add layoutIfNeeded as well

Comment: we are testing the application , everything works fine in this view controller (which we named it second view controller) . but I have another problem  in the total  view hierarchy . when the UIimage picker dismissed the previous view controllers ' frame changed . view hierarchy----> tabbarcontroller - navigation controller - first viewcontroller . I mean the first view controller frame has problem now does it need to add another navigation controller before second view controller?

Comment: the solution works only in current View but another View controller corrupt ( going to bottom )

Answer (score 0):

When I applied the @Mohamad Solution after updating the frame when I tapped on the textView its was showing blank black area above the keyboard and when I returned back from the controller Tabbar shifted down so I implemented the **Below code is a permanent solution**.

```
@property CGRect viewFrame;
@property CGRect tabbarFrame;

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
if (CGRectIsEmpty(self.viewFrame)) {
        self.viewFrame=self.view.frame;
        self.tabbarFrame=self.tabBarController.view.frame;
    }
}
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
 [self correctScreenSize];
}
-(void)correctScreenSize
{
    self.view.frame = self.viewFrame;
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    self.tabBarController.view.frame  = self.tabbarFrame;
    [self.tabBarController.view layoutIfNeeded];

}
```