# Layout gets messy after dismissing the MFmailComposeViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

My problem is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32455429/wrong-screen-size-after-dismissing-uiimagepickercontroller)

But I am embedding my view in scrollview and by following this article my problem still persist, is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Can you please share screens?

Answer (score 0):

When you present a `PickerView` or `MFMailComposeViewController` then just write the following code.

```
[[[[AppDelegate sharedInstance] window] rootViewController] presentViewController:aImagePicker animated:YES completion:nil]
```

May be this code will help you.

Answer (score 0):

If the page layout has become wrong, particularly in a tableview or scrollview you can call :

```
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
```

Which will go over all autolayout and move it about to correct it if required.  I suggest you call that after dismissing the MFMailComposeViewController to be sure.